# Selenium hub fails loading giving an error could not find non loopback ip address

Tags: java, selenium

I ran selenium server standalone(selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar) as usual and it worked fine. in windows I entered  `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar` in the command line.

But when I tried to run selenium hub giving the parameters`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub` it pops up an error saying that

`Exception in thread main org.openqa.selenium.webdriverexception:could not find a non-loop back ip4 address`

could someone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it several time removing the registry values also for the installation. and finally noticed that its some kind of a problem with the internet connection. don’t' know for sure. But when I changed my internet connection from dongle to a land-line. it worked. Still don't know the reason. but finally it worked.