# Selenium Grid: "Could not find a non-loopback ip4 address for this machine" and "An illegal reflective access operation has occurred"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to setup a Selenium Grid with hub in Windows10 and node in Ubuntu. I have installed ubuntu in virtualbox(running in my HOST win10). When I try to register a node, getting error as "Could not find a non-loopback ip4 address for this machine". I have no clue on the issue. Please help to resolve.

Similar question i found in the forum but there is no clear solution.

When I connected to LAN, getting the following message.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cound not find a non-loopback ip4 address for this machine
```

If I switch to Wifi, different error occurs as below.

```
-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/home/mehamgn/Documents/drivers/geckodriver/" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig grid_node.json
18:54:46.792 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3'
18:54:46.860 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 5555
2018-05-24 18:54:51.656:INFO::main: Logging initialized @14625ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
18:54:55.286 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 5555
18:54:55.294 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
18:54:55.383 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 10000 ms.
18:54:55.388 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.openqa.selenium.json.BeanToJsonConverter (file:/home/mehamgn/Documents/selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar) to method sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.getDeclaredAnnotations()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.openqa.selenium.json.BeanToJsonConverter
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
18:55:00.088 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
18:55:10.159 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
18:55:20.171 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
18:55:30.181 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
18:55:40.185 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
18:55:50.198 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
```

nodeConfig JSON file

```
{
    "capabilities":
[
    {
        "browserName":"firefox",
        "version":"60.0.1",
        "maxInstances":1
        },
        {
            "browserName":"chrome",
            "version":"66.0.3359.181",
            "maxInstances":1
            }],
            "port":5555,
            "hubHost":"192.168.2.8",
            "hubPort":4444,
            "registerCycle":10000,
            "register":true,
            "timeout":0,
            "maxSessions":2
        }
```

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: @DebanjanB updated with actual text. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cound not find a non-loopback ip4 address for this machine
```

...implies that there was some issue while reading the ip4 address due to a possible change in **/etc/hosts** (Ubuntu) file or **\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts** (Windows) file.

You can find a similar discussion in [**`Selenium hub fails loading giving an error could not find non loopback ip address`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224693/selenium-hub-fails-loading-giving-an-error-could-not-find-non-loopback-ip-addres)

This second error message...

```
18:54:55.388 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.openqa.selenium.json.BeanToJsonConverter (file:/home/mehamgn/Documents/selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar) to method sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.getDeclaredAnnotations()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.openqa.selenium.json.BeanToJsonConverter
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
18:55:00.088 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
18:55:10.159 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
```

...implies that the *Selenium Grid Node* wasn't registered successfully to the *Selenium Grid Hub*

However the command to start the *Selenium Grid Node* looks errorprone and should be as follows :

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/home/mehamgn/Documents/drivers/geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig grid_node.json
```

**Note**:

- The value of `-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver` must end with the binary name e.g. **geckodriver** (omit the trailing `/`)
- Ensure that you pass the exact **nodeConfig.json** file (as per your code you are using `grid_node.json`)

Comment: 1) How to ensure `/etc/hosts` files are correctly placed. I have gone through the page you suggested but it didn't help. 2) I tried as per your comments but still facing issue `mehamgn@mehamgn-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/home/mehamgn/Documents/drivers/geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig grid_node.json` `21:08:35.088 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444`

Comment: I tried with selenium-server-standalone-**3.11.0**.jar version instead of **3.12.0** , it works. But it doesn't look like version issue.

Comment: The issue is intermittent. When I connected today, same error occurs. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: The issue mainly occurs when i use `nodeConfig` to configure capabilities. If I mention all capabilities in command line, everything works fine. Need to look into the json file.

Comment: `nodeConfig` works in Standalone 3.9.1 version. Finding a working configuration seems to be magical.